# ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached. Oracle Apex 5 with BI Publisher 11.1.1.7

Tags: bi-publisher, oracle-apex-5

I am working on Apex 5, want to run bi publihser report with apex.
I created instance in Manage Instance>Report Printing of apex
Host Address : localhost
Port:7001
Print Server: /xmlpserver/convert

Now created report query but when i click "Test Report Query"
it shows me error
ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached because either the URL specified is incorrect or a proxy URL needs to be specified.

My BI configure components are
Configure Components

```
    Oracle Enterprise Manager
        http://naeemshahzad-PC:7001/em
    Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition
        naeemshahzad-PC:9704/analytics
    Business Intelligence Publisher
        naeemshahzad-PC:9704/xmlpserver
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this error :

```
ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached because either the URL specified is incorrect or a proxy URL needs to be specified.
```

is because by default, the ability to interact with network services is disabled in `Oracle Database 12c`. Therefore, if you are running `Oracle Application Express 5.0` with `Oracle Database 12c`, you must use the new `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN` package to grant connect privileges to any host for the `APEX_050000` database user.

Therefore you should grant connect privilages to `APEX_050000`

Solution:

Connect to database where Oracle Application Express is installed as `SYS` specifying the `SYSDBA` role. (connect to sqlplus by sys as sysdba user)

Then run following plsql:

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_050000
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_050000 does not have the privilege yet.

  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050000',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

after that run:

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to 'localhost' and give APEX_050000
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_040200 does not have the privilege yet.
  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = 'localhost' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050000',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to 'localhost'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('local-access-users.xml',
    'ACL that lets users to connect to localhost',
    'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('local-access-users.xml','localhost');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Gives me ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44416: Invalid ACL: Unresolved principal 'APEX_050000'
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 252
ORA-06512: at line 19
ORA-01403: no data found

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check:

```
manage instance> instance settings> print server host address
```

Maybe you just changed the IP Address.