# Oracle-APEX-18.2 error ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached...

Tags: oracle-apex

I opened the Oracle SQL Developer and created a connection as SYSDBA. I opened a SQL code window and pasted the code below 1st part and ran it, then I pasted 2nd part and ran. Both procedures gave me (PL / SQL procedure successfully) as result, but I still getting the ORA-2100 error. I even restart my PC but still getting the error.

Do you have any tip? Am I missing something?
   I just have installed Oracle 11g and Apex 18.2. Should I install anything else?

Here are the codes:

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_050000
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_050000 does not have the privilege 
yet.

  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050000',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

after that I ran:

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to 'localhost' and give 
APEX_050000
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_040200 does not have the privilege 
yet.
  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = 'localhost' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050000',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to 'localhost'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('local-access-users.xml',
    'ACL that lets users to connect to localhost',
    'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('local-access-users.xml','localhost');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

I copied this code from other post [ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached. Oracle Apex 5 with BI Publisher 11.1.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103875/ora-20001-the-printing-engine-could-not-be-reached-oracle-apex-5-with-bi-publi)

and just changed APEX_50000 references to APEX_180200 to match my version.